# Where should I put the credentials: application.properties vs system env variables

Tags: java, spring

In my spring boot project, where should I put the credentials to use different services, such as username/password for the database or message queue, or the JWT secret key?

Should I put it in a system env variable? or in application.properties? which one is more secure? considering that both are in plain text?

For JWT token I use the following command in OS to update the value before firing up the server:

```
export MONEYLIZER_JWT_SECRET_KEY=$(echo -n "somevalue" | openssl sha512 -hmac "somekey")
```

So it's not always constant. `application.properties` doesn't give me this flexibility.

What is usually done for commercial services? where should I keep the credentials and settings?

Comment: Its more secure to put in env variables if you are not using a cloud vault like spring vault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Environment variables are definitely more secure than plain-text in application.properties

> Typical Sping-based deployments suffer from configuration being hard
>   coded into the application properties files of the code repository.
>   This is great for modularizing your code base so it can be transported
>   to multiple environments. However it ensures your code also has clear
>   text passwords, api keys and other data that shouldn't be in a VCS
>   repo or distributed in any way.
>
> In order to lock down the security of the code base itself we decided
>   to externalize all the passwords, api keys and other confidential data
>   from our code base. Spring makes it remarkably easy to do this,
>   providing the options to specify configuration as environment
>   variables at boot or specify external application property files to an
>   init script or CLI call.

[veracode blog](https://www.veracode.com/blog/managing-appsec/externalizing-data-secure-spring-boot-deployments)

Comment: Oh nice. So it's possible to use external properties file instead of one living in the project.

Comment: External, internal, result of API call - look l